# Python | Give list [1,2,3,4] -> return 1*2+2*3+3*4

Tags: python, numpy

So as i said in the title, i want to multipy each two neigbors in the list and sum them all - with a single code line.

I'm looking for the most elegant and efficient method, without using extra memory or such.

Here's what I do have now:

```
import numpy as np
G = lambda array: sum(np.multiply(array[:-1], array[1:])))
```

That works, but when i write `array[:-1]` and `array[1:]`, doesn't it create two new arrays? If so, is there a way to do that with the same original array?

Or maybe you can come up with a nicer way to do that :)

Comment: `numpy` is very smart about memory.  That creates two new array OBJECTS, but the objects don't own the memory.  `numpy` arrays point to internal memory, and `numpy` will try to make slices like that share the same underlying memory.  Even if it didn't, unless your array has many millions of entries, the cost of those arrays will be minimal.

Comment: And by the way, if `array` is a numpy array, you can write that as `np.sum(array[:-1] * array[1:])`.  `numpy` was designed for these kinds of operations.

Comment: Oh that's some very useful information! Well thank you very much @TimRoberts !

Comment: @TimRoberts or even `array[1:] @ array[:-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    lst = [1,2,3,4]
    func = lambda lst: sum([lst[i]*lst[i+1] for i in range(len(lst)-1)])
    func(lst)
```

Comment: With `numpy` data, that's clearly NOT the best solution.

Comment: Looks great!
@TimRoberts why is it not good?

Comment: @ryden `for` loops in python are slow.  For a 4-element list it's not noticeable, but get more than a few hundred and this solution will be painfully slow.  `numpy` does the loops in compiled `c` code under the hood, which is much faster.  It also, as @TimRoberts mentioned is much smarter about memory allocation, and has tricks to be smarter still for some operations.

Answer (score 2):

The actual `numpy` way

```
array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

array[1:] @ array[:-1]

Out[]: 20
```

`@` is the dot-product operator, which is what that multiply-sum operation is called normally.

If you're wedded to the `lambda`, it would be:

```
G = lambda array: array[1:] @ array[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not constrained by the lambda you can:

```
def sum_with_neighbours(arr: list[int]) -> int:
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):  # -1 because we want to go until second-last item
        sum_ += arr[i] * arr[i + 1]
    return sum_
```

Comment: That works, but that's not a single code line :)

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.pairwise` may be the most pythonic choice:

```
>>> from itertools import pairwise
>>> [*pairwise(range(5))]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
>>> sum(i * j for i, j in pairwise(range(5)))
20
```

Comment: @Nick This is just an example. It works for any iterable sequence.